# How can I support using streams in an exception handling macro in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, macros

I have a little error function that looks like this:

```
    template<typename ErrorType>
    void throwError(const std::string &file,
                    const std::string &function,
                    unsigned int line,
                    const std::string &msg = "") {
        std::ostringstream errMsg;
        errMsg << file << ":" << line << ":" << function << ":"
               << "\nError: " << msg << std::endl;
        std::cerr << errMsg.str();
        throw ErrorType(errMsg.str());
    }
```

Then I have some macros that use the function:

```
#define INVALID_ARGUMENT_ERROR(msg) throwError<std::invalid_argument>(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, msg)
#define LOGIC_ERROR(msg) throwError<std::logic_error>(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, msg)
```

So I can do:

```
if (condition == bad)
    LOGIC_ERROR("you did a bad");
```

But this is quite invonvenient when I want to add additional information in the error message, like values of numbers for example.

What would be a good way of modifying this function so that it enables me to use a stream instead of a string? So I want do be able to do:

```
if (condition == bad)
    LOGIC_ERROR("you did a bad because condition \"" << condition << " != " << bad);
```

I've tried changing the `std::string string msg` to a `std::ostringstream` which does not work.

Comment: You can use `std::to_string()` to convert the conditions to string and use the `+` operator to concatenate the fragmented string into one string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to change the syntax slightly then a simple helper macro could be used.  Given your current function template...

```
template<typename ErrorType>
void throwError(const std::string &file,
                const std::string &function,
                unsigned int line,
                const std::string &msg = "")
{
    std::ostringstream errMsg;
    errMsg << file << ":" << line << ":" << function << ":"
           << "\nError: " << msg << std::endl;
    std::cerr << errMsg.str();
    throw ErrorType(errMsg.str());
}
```

you can then define...

```
#define THROW_HELPER(ex_type)                                           \
    for (std::stringstream ss; true; throwError<ex_type>(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, ss.str())) \
        ss

#define INVALID_ARGUMENT_ERROR THROW_HELPER(std::invalid_argument)
#define LOGIC_ERROR            THROW_HELPER(std::logic_error)
```

These can then be used as, e.g...

```
LOGIC_ERROR << "extra messages go here";
```

Note that currently two separate `std::stringstream` instances are created in the process of throwing an exception so the code shown should probably be 'compacted' a bit to prevent that [left as an exercise :-) ].

Answer (score 0):

I propose a different option: [libfmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)!

```
#define LOGIC_ERROR(...) \
    throwError<std::logic_error>(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, fmt::format(__VA_ARGS__))
```

Usage:

```
if (condition == bad)
    LOGIC_ERROR("you did a bad because condition {} != {}", condition, bad);
```

---

The downside of this approach is that `fmt::format` will throw an exception if the format string is invalid. You could instead check it at compile-time using `FMT_STRING()` macro:

```
#define LOGIC_ERROR(string) \
    throwError<std::logic_error>(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, string)

#define LOGIC_ERROR_P(string, ...) \
    throwError<std::logic_error>(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, \
    fmt::format(FMT_STRING(string), __VA_ARGS__))
```

Here I've created two versions of `LOGIC_ERROR` with and without extra parameters. It possible to have a single a single macro dispatch between those two depending on the number of arguments, but that's left as an exercise to the reader.